# Boxplot sees values that aren't there

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a [IMDB dataset](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~hladka/2016/docs/mov.development.csv) and trying to make a boxplot of a film's ratings.

I've successfully loaded the dataset and tried to make the boxplot but it produced a really weird result.

It looked as it tried to make a boxplot for all the films and not just the one selected.

`boxplot(rating ~ title, data=imdb[imdb$title == "Top Gun (1986)", ])`

The graph produced: 
[image]

As you can see the y axis looks as if it contained films that aren't in the filtered dataset at all (I selected those via title).

Comment: Try `data=droplevels(imdb[imdb$title == "Top Gun (1986)", ])`

Comment: You sir, are amazing!

Care to write a proper answer so I can close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors retain their levels even after subsetting, you can drop those that are unused with `droplevels`:

```
boxplot(rating ~ title, data=droplevels(imdb[imdb$title == "Top Gun (1986)", ]))
```